# Detect 360 degree video

Tags: 360-degrees, 360-virtual-reality

I want to Detect 360 degree video
I want to find if the video format is 360 degree and based on that manage the player supported the 360 degree
So anybody can help ?

Comment: Okay cool, from what language/platform are you approaching this?

Answer (score 2):

It seems that the 360video/VR standards are still in flux.  This article, http://labs.dash.umn.edu/etc-lab/detecting-spherical-media-files/,  (dated April 2016) suggests that inspecting the EXIF properties of the photo/video might reveal a pattern in the metadata.  There are libraries available to access EXIF data from files, such as this:  https://github.com/exif-js/exif-js.  PHP libraries exist as well. Phil Harvey's website ( http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/) has a wealth of information and coding examples.  There are compiled tools for WIN, MAC and NIX and a C++ library as well.  From personal experience, EXIF values can be read from JPEG files.  I have never tried accessing 360 JPEGs, but it is my understanding that the photo files produced from spherical cameras are nothing but regular JPEGs (although the images appear distorted when viewed without a 360 viewer).  The EXIF tool that Phil Harvey has written shows support for mp4.  You may be able to use the tool to analyze 360 videos to look for discernible patterns in the metadata.